# .dll only works properly on Windows XP and Vista but not 7?

Tags: c, windows, dll, backwards-compatibility

I have a windows .dll file (from a third-party - which have discontinued supporting it and I don't have the C sourcecode to rectify the problems).

I'm using the .dll in a project of mine.

The .dll file works perfectly fine under Windows XP/Vista (as it was released at the time of when these OS versions were current/latest) - the issue is now that the project is now limited to Windows XP/Vista users (due to that .dll) - when it runs under Windows 7 it slightly malfunctions (ie. produces different results then compared to Windows XP/Vista).

I believe the problem is Microsoft must have changed something (within the Windows library or something?) which is effecting the compatibility.

So I was wondering - I know its not really the best option but as a temporary/hackish workaround is their someway I can emulate Windows XP/Vista functionality for the Windows 7 users, ie. is their any projects designed for this - example => http://www.busybox.net/about.html (which allows Linux functionality to be able to be executed on Windows).

Appreciate all suggestions/workarounds.

Comment: Some Windows 7 have a full XP in them, where you can run legacy programs in some sort of transparent container thingy. I think you right-click on the EXE and go through some wizard.

Comment: What is the compatibility issue?  That is, when you say it "slightly malfunctions" and "produces different results", what exactly are those differences?  I ask because there are folks knowledgable of OS compatibility differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7, you can run an executable in Compatibility Mode, and set it to run in a mode compatible with Windows XP.  For details, see [Make older programs run in this version of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-Windows).

---

Note that, you can't force this .DLL to always use a compatibility mode, but you can change your installer to make the appropriate registry settings for the user or machine that do this.

All you need to do is add a registry key as follows.  Under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Application Compatibility\Layers
```

Add a key like:

```
"Path\To\Program\YourExecutable.exe"=WINXPSP2
```

This will cause your program to always run under compat mode.  You can also set this in HKCU if you prefer to just set it for the current user.

Comment: Thank you, although is their a generic/automated way to make these changes for the specific .dll? - I'd like to make it as easy as possible for the end user to use - instead of going through several steps.

Comment: @newbtophp: You can't set to a .DLL, but can set it on your exe.  I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Thank you for the informative edit, however unfourtanetly this does not resolve my problem as the core is within the .dll, and Compatibility Mode only accepts .exe extensions.

Comment: @newbtophp: Just do this for every app that uses the .exe.  There is no option that's DLL specific.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds too easy: But what about Windows Compatibility Mode? Maybe it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running your app on Windows 7 under [Windows XP Compatibility mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-compatibility-mode/) and compare the results to those from native Windows XP.